# CLion: "Remote GDB Server" targeting Windows

Tags: c++, remote-debugging, clion

Is it possible to run a remote debug session targeting Windows with CLion?
The docs say that I can do any system that has *gdbserver*:

> Remote OS: any supporting gdbserver and SSH

However, when I try to run my remote app, I get an error:

```
10:53 PM    Build finished in 3 sec, 44 ms

10:53 PM    Error running 'remote'
                1: 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
                operable program or batch file.
```

I can't find a place where I could see the whole command that CLion runs that causes this error.
Here is my configuration:
[image]

Comment: It seems like you entered the enviroment details in the credentials part. Put them in the Target section.

Comment: **and SSH**. And apparently whatever this `env` command is. You may need to install a more-unix-like toolchain like msys2 on your remote windows box.

Comment: @user4581301 I am using gdbserver from msys2 for mingw64. And OpenSSH service

Comment: @AlonAdler I didn't, at least not in the forms. There are login and password fields. And I can't see the result command generated by CLion

Comment: Groovy. Make sure the path being used on the remote includes the msys bin directory or (usually better) explicitly specify it. And Since I don't know how to do that with clion, I'll shut up now.

Comment: @user4581301 you are right. Windows OpenSSH Server uses `cmd.exe`, which does not have `env`

Comment: msys2 should, or at least or does when I'm done installing it, have the `env` command. For the sake of the experiment, add the msys bin directory to the remote computer's system path and see if that solves it. Might need a reboot to get everyone agreeing on the new path. Once you've proved the concept out, you can figure out a better way to get things working.

Comment: @user4581301 it does. `/usr/bin/env.exe`

Comment: I wonder, what kind of settings are available in `Advanced GDB Server Options`?

Comment: @ssbssa `Working directory`, `Environment Variables`, `Run with root priviliges` and `Startup delay`

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I have come to the conclusion that it is impossible to remote debug a Windows app with CLion 2021.3.1 (regardless of Host platform).

CLion does not support remote debugging when targeting Windows OS using GDB Server (hence targeting Windows is impossible) due to:

1. CLion does not handle cases when SSH Server is using a non-Unix shell like *CMD.exe* or *PowerShell*. Commands like *exec*, *env*, *chmod* can’t be handled. *This can be circumvented by using a Unix shell:*
   **a.** Unfortunately, connection fails for *MSYS2 Bash* and *Git Bash* when Windows OpenSSH Server is configured to use one as a default shell.
   **b.** Windows WSL SSH Server works. Connection is established, Unix commands are recognized. *WSL must be installed. It is not easy to configure WSL when Windows itself is running on virtual machine.*
   **c.** MinGW64 SSH Server. Didn’t test it.
2. Uploading binaries via SFTP fails when OpenSSH Service is used. Can be circumvented with **1.b.**.
3. CLion doesn’t consider the binary’s file extension. It *always* assumes that the binary is built for Linux, hence the attempt to transfer fails, when a binary has an *.exe* extension (fails to find *test*, though *test.exe* was built). *This is a major bug that prevents remote debugging targeting Windows*. There are, however, ways to work around:
   **a.** Manual renaming before running debug. *Unacceptable.*
   **b.** Adding a conditional custom CMake command. *May work but pollutes the CMakeLists.txt*
4. *CLion can’t connect to MinGW GDB Server it has started.* Connection times out. However, if the Server was started from a terminal, CLion connects successfully and is able to run debug as intended. *This can ONLY be worked around MANUALLY*:
   **a.** In *Edit Configurations…* one must put a stub command in *GDB Server:*, for example ‘sleep’. In *GDB Server args:* ‘5’. This will give a time to manually run the *gdbserver.exe* command via an SSH connection in *Terminal*.

These issues were reproduced for CLion versions for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.
**3.** and **4.** are very serious and prevent from remote debugging targeting Windows as it was intended to be done.

This happens when CLion connects to the Server it has started:
[image]

This is a work around:
[image]
[image]
[image]

As can be seen from the screenshots, with this approach GDB’s console does not catch the output. You must switch to *Terminal* to see it.