# Can GCC's gdbserver be used to debug MinGW-w64-compiled application?

Tags: c++, windows, gdb, cross-platform, remote-debugging

This is an XY question because I still haven't found a solution for my initial [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70440973/9363996).

However, I'd like to know (at least out of curiosity) the answer. This might help to understand  how *gdbserver* works.

1. Given a mingw-w64 compiled binary to run on Windows, can a GCC gdbserver (launched on WSL) debug this binary? **It seems that it can: see UPDATE**
2. Will it work with WSL's mingw-w64 gdb? (run CLion on WSL to remotelly debug Windows app)
3. Can I "cheat" mingw-w64 to connect to the GCC gdbserver? Obviously, it refuses to work:

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.0.101:1234
Remote debugging using 192.168.0.101:1234
warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this configuration
of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default i386:x86-64 settings.

warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Reading /init from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this configuration
of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default i386:x86-64 settings.

warning: Architecture of file not recognized.
Reading /init from remote target...
Reading symbols from target:/init...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Remote register badly formatted: T0506:0000000000000000;07:a0e5feffff7f0000;10:0060220000000000;thread:p1007.1007;core:0;
here: 00000000;07:a0e5feffff7f0000;10:0060220000000000;thread:p1007.1007;core:0;
```

`msys64/mingw64/gdbserver.exe` is a bad option:

- CLion does not want to connect when CLion is the one to start the server
- the server constantly crashes
  And I couldn't find an alternative for gdbserver on Windows.

---

So far I have a configuration:

- Windows with MinGW-w64 compiler to build an app (using CLion as an IDE)
- Remote Virtual Windows machine to remotelly debug the app (CLion does not support MSVC's remote debugger)
- WSL Ubuntu on Virtual Windows (bruh) - this is needed for a proper shell with sshd (git bash/msys64 bash/mingw64 mintty do not work as Windows OpenSSH shells. No matter how hard i tried).

---

### UPDATE

So I launched WSL `/usr/bin/gdbserver :1234 test` on my Virtual Windows. Then I launched WSL `/usr/bin/gdb` from my local Windows machine.
And it didn't show any errors:

```
eld@RU-AI000174:~$ gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) target remote 192.168.0.101:1234
Remote debugging using 192.168.0.101:1234
Reading /init from remote target...
warning: File transfers from remote targets can be slow. Use "set sysroot" to access files locally instead.
Reading /init from remote target...
Reading symbols from target:/init...
(No debugging symbols found in target:/init)
0x0000000000226000 in ?? ()
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 1202) exited normally]
```

Is this an expected and/or reliable behavior?